# Arranging server component ducks

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to find an **elegant** framework to arrange all of my server components.

The server:

```
1. Receives a request, as a XML string, from the client.

2. Validates the messages ( !null && !empty mainly).

3. Unmarshalls the message into a Request object.

4. Validates the internals of the Request object (ensures all the required fields are there, ie. id, requestName etc).

5. If valid, create a specific request (I receive a lot of extra information in the original request and I need a very small subset of it to process the request).

6. Process the request and retrieve the output.

7. Send the output to the client.
```

Currently, my design look something like this:

```
Controller{

processMessage(String requestMsg){
boolean isValid = validator.validate(requestMsg);
Request request = creator.createRequest(requestMsg);
isValid = validator.validate(request);
processor.processRequest();

}
```

The controller class is composed of the validators, creators and processors.
Once a request is received, the template of validate - create - process is followed.

Now all of this works but I can't help to wonder whether I can arrange these components in a better way. Better being more loosely coupled.

Is there a framework which I could perhaps use? Any ideas, tips, links would be greatly helpful.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Spring](http://www.springframework.org).  It has a binding and validation API, web controllers, a well-defined service tier based on POJO interfaces.

Even if you don't use the framework, it's a great example of good Java design.

Comment: Thanks duffymo, I have started looking into it.